# Is there an infinite product like this for $\cos x$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, infinite-product, nested-radicals

There are infinite products of iterated square roots for $\log x$ and $\arccos x$ in function of $x$. For example

$$ (1) \log x = \frac{x - 1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\left ( \frac{1 + x}{2\sqrt{2}} \right )}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\left ( \frac{1 + x}{2\sqrt{2}} \right )...}}}$$

$$ (2)  \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\arccos x} = \frac{\sqrt{2+2x}}{2}\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2x}}}{2}\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2x}}}}{2}...$$

Keeping this in mind, I wonder if there is an infinite product of square roots, similar to those products above, for $\cos x$, as a function of $x$.

Are the identities $(1)$ and $(2)$ helpful in obtaining a similar product for $ \cos x $? If not, is there any infinite product with square roots, which can be derived in some way, or is there some demonstration that such product can not exist?

References:

An infinite product of nested radicals for from
the Archimedean algorithm log x

Thomas J. Osler, Walter Jacob and Ryo Nishimura.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Specifically, I refer to a product similar to the ones above, in which the number $\pi $ does not appear, as in Weierstrass's product, but a combination of square roots and rational numbers and the $x$ number. This isn't a formal definition, but, with the identities above as examples, it makes pretty clear what I want.

Comment: So is $$\cos(x)=\prod_{n\geq 0}\sqrt{\left(1-\frac{H \sqrt{x}^4}{(2n+1)^2}\right)^2}$$ with $H=\frac{4}{\pi^2}$ fine?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Not really. You may want to return with a non-trivial answer to the question, or say that you don't know. Also, avoid the mathematical pedantry of "If a problem is not rigorously defined, I will pretend that I do not understand it".

Comment: @FractionalInquirer: all right, but you may also want to comply with the rules for asking a good question here. In its current state, yours is not, with or without my nitpicking.